# Byte of Python. 15.1 Ввод от пользователя

Tags: python, python-3.x

не могу понять что надо делать, помогите!

"Домашнее задание
Проверка, является ли текст палиндромом должна также игнорировать знаки пунктуации, пробелы и регистр букв. Например, «А роза упала на лапу Азора» также является
палиндромом, но наша текущая программа так не считает. Попробуйте улучить её так,
чтобы она распознала этот палиндром.
Подсказка: (не читайте)
Воспользуйтесь кортежем (список всех знаков пунктуации можно найти здесь), содержащим все запрещённые символы, и примените тест на принадлежность, чтобы обнаружить символы, подлежащие удалению, т.е. forbidden = (‘!’, ‘?’, ‘.’, …)."

Мой код:

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def is_palindrome(text):
    return text == reverse(text)

something = input('Введите текст: ')
if (is_palindrome(something)):
    print("Да, это палиндром")
else:
    print("Нет, это не палиндром")
```

Comment: Подсказкой воспользовались или не стали?

Comment: Воспользовался, но я всё равно не особо понял как сделать и вставить в свой код.
Я прям совсем зелёный в этом(

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю ещё один рабочий вариант (хотя возможно это дубликат и всё это было в ответах на другие вопросы):

```
from string import punctuation

punctuation += ' '

def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def normalize(text):
    return ''.join(filter(lambda c: c not in punctuation, text.lower()))

def is_palindrome(text):
    text = normalize(text)
    return text == reverse(text)

assert is_palindrome('А роза упала на лапу Азора!')
assert is_palindrome('А, что, где? едг отча')
assert not is_palindrome('Да ну фигня какая-то')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def is_palindrome(text):
    return text == reverse(text)

delims = ('.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '-', '(', ')', '[', ']', '"', ',')
something = input('Введите текст: ')
something = something.lower()   #  перевод в нижний регистр
for i in range(len(something)):
    for x in delims:
        if something[i] == x:
            something = something.replace(x, ' ')   #   замена разделителя на пробел
list = something.split()   #  разбивка на части по символам пробела
#print(list)
s = ""
for x in list:
    s += x      #  конкатенация частей в слово без разделителей
#print(s)
if (is_palindrome(s)):
    print("Да, это палиндром")
else:
    print("Нет, это не палиндром")
```

Список разделителей в кортеже delims можете расширить.

Comment: Спасибо)
А что за "delims"?
Я его в книге еще не встречал.

Comment: Список знаков пунктуации, которые программа должна игнорировать при проверке на палиндром, назван мной delims (от английского "delimeters" - разделители). Он здесь неполный, по сравнению со списком, указанным в подсказке автором книги. Дополнить (при желании)  можете сами.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]


def mark_test(text):
    text = text.lower() // Перевод всей строки в нижний регистр
    marks = (' ', '.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '-', '(', ')', '[', ']', '"', ',')

    for item in marks:
        text = text.replace(item, '') // Удаляет символы из строки указанные в кортеже marks
    return text


def is_palindrome(text):
    text = mark_test(text)
    return text == reverse(text)


something = input('enter text: ')

if is_palindrome(something):
    print('This is palindrome')
else:
    print('This is not palindrome')
```

Немного покороче

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```py
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def is_palindrome(text):
    return text == reverse(text)

something = input("Enter text: ")
something = something.lower()
f = filter(str.isalpha, something)
s1 = "".join(f)
print(s1)

if is_palindrome(s1):
    print("Yes, it is a palindrome")
else:
    print("No, it is not a palindrome")
```

Правда автор просил решить с использованием tuple.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]